# Find whether the following point of straight lines are intersecting or skew,if they intersect find the point of intersection

Tags: geometry

My attempt:
Let $\frac{x-6}{1}=\frac{y+2}{5}=\frac{z+2}{7}=t$
and $\frac{x-1}{3}=\frac{y-3}{5}=\frac{2-z}{-8}=s$
$L_1$:$x=t+6$;$y=5t-2$;$z=7t-2$
$L_2$:$x=3s+1$;$y=5s+3$;$z=2+8s$

$t+6=3s+1$
=>$t=3s-5$
Again 
$5t-2=5s+3$
=>$15s-25-2=5s+3$
=>$s=3$
Substituting s we get
$t=4$
Therefore they are intersecting at one point and the point is $x=4+6$
   => $=10$,
$y=18$,
$z=26$

Pardon me if I did any mistake while writing. I am trying my best.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check whether the point you found $(10,18,26)$ on both lines.

$$\frac{10-6}{1}=\frac{18+2}{5}=\frac{26+2}7$$ holds, they are equal to $4$. The point lies on the first line.

$$\frac{10-1}{3}=\frac{18-3}{5}=\frac{2-26}{-8}$$ holds, they are equal to $3$. The point lies on the second  line.

Also, $(1,5,7)$ and $(3,5,8)$ are not multiple of each other, they are not parallel to each other.

You have solved the problem correctly.

Comment: I was worried if it was right or wrong. Now i am relieved.